# Command line Interface in Agent in Nolio

Tags: nolio

To upload manifest file at the time of deployment, I want that there should be prompt every time for uploading manifest file, the previous manifest file should not be picked up automatically.
For this, is there any option in ROC? With CLI, since I dont have the access to the main server can I install CLI on Agent? It would be great if I can have a clear process for installation on Agent, I am confused with documents available.
I have one running Agent.
Thanks in Advance.